# onChange title functions doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have code

```
var dctitle = document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[1]
dctitle.onchange = function() {
    alert("catched");
    console.log("catched");
};
```

This code looking for class1 title and when title of class1 changed, alert and console.log should execute, but actually doesn't.
dctitle is correct array and monitors any changes in class1 title, but function don't work.
What wrong with code? I'm new for js and trying to google already. Sorry for my english.

Element

```
<div class="class1" title="123"></div>
```

Comment: what kind of element is it?

Comment: a) `dctitle` is not an array, it's either a DOM element or `undefined`. Will there always be at least two elements with that class and do you always want to target the second element? b) JavaScript is case sensitive, the property is called `onChange`. c) What type of element is `dctitle`? Not every element triggers a `change` event.

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: Also note that JS arrays\* are zero-based, so `[1]` will index the *second* element.  `[0]` to take the first.  (\*Yes, technically JS doesn't have arrays.)

Comment: I posted HTML. Sorry.

Comment: Aside from all the points in my previous comment, `<div>` elements don't trigger a change event. Changing the value of an attribute (I assume that's what your are trying to achieve) never triggers a change event anyway. If you explain the problem you are actually trying to solve, we can help you better.

Comment: It seems that the OP actually looks for DOM Mutation Events. Still I smell XY problem here.

Comment: @a1061384 Start looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - or, even better, describe the _actual_ problem you face, not the solution you think about.

Comment: @FelixKling I need to make my code execute when div title changed, i've tried with onChange, but you guys confirmed it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The ".onchange" event can only be applied to inputs, plus if you wanted to select the first instance of class name "class1" then you'd have to set your dctitle variable with [0] not [1]. The onchange event will be fired when the user interacts with the field. Here's a working example:

HTML:

```
<input class="class1" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var dctitle = document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0];
dctitle.onchange = function() {
    alert("catched");
    console.log("catched");
};
```

Here's a link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xanco/uzfLug8j/

If you want to read more about the onchange event, you can go to: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way i can track my div title changed?

Comment: @a1061384 Sorry for the delay, what do you mean "track my div title changed"? If you tell me, I can help you further